# How to check all <p:selectBooleanCheckbox/> boolean Checkboxes by checking one check box with javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf-2

I have `</p:dataTable>` of jsf which contains a main `<p:selectBooleanCheckbox >` in one header column.Under this column I have more `<p:selectBooleanCheckbox >`.I need to check the main `<p:selectBooleanCheckbox >` and then all the other check boxes should be checked.IfI uncheked the main one all others should be unchecked too.I have tried many examples but the did not work.I need this to be done with javaScript.

```
<p:dataTable value="#{userMassTransferBean.recordList}" var="record">
    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Transfer To "/> 
            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="mainCheckbox" />
        </f:facet>
        <p:selectBooleanCheckbox  id="subCheckbox" value="#{userMassTransferBean.selected}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

I have used some javaScripts which found from internet but they gave me error like

> setter not found for property class

So I used styleClass attribute inside the `<p:selectBooleanCheckbox >` tag,but then the script did not worked.Please do not mark this as duplicate and I need to do this with javaScript.

Comment: Why don't you use `<p:dataTable>`'s own row selection feature? http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml

Answer (score 0):

it seems you are using primefaces to create the table. If you want use only javascript Is better show the generated html. Hovewer I think is not a good idea to use the same value for the ID attribute, that must be unique in the html page. The error "setter not found for property class" is showed when you use the attribute Class that's not the style sheet class, for that aim is used the styleClass attribute that adds a css class to the component.